# Buildozer's APK keeps crashing even with Pillow

Tags: kivy, python-imaging-library, apk, kivymd, buildozer

i am trying to convert a python app to apk, it crashes every time even when i add pillow and precise kivy and kivymd versions (btw i am not sure about the versions if they are correct).
Here are my buildozer.spec requirements :
`python3,kivy==2.2.1,kivymd==1.1.1,pillow,requests,datetime,arabic_reshaper,python-bidi,python-math`
And imported modules in main.py :

```
import requests
import locale
import math
import datetime
import arabic_reshaper
import bidi.algorithm
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
```

I precise that i also have an 'icon.png' file and '.ttf' file. Should i replace pillow by pil ?
Here is the catlog i took, i don't thing it is complete but it is long : https://github.com/MarkLeVrai/WeatherApp/blob/main/catlog.txt

Can you help me to find the problem ?